# Run vs. Debug = different results in Assembler

Tags: c#, assembly

I'm learning assembler. I practise with this code:

**ASM:**

```
    ;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
.586 

.MODEL flat, stdcall
public srednia_harm 


OPTION CASEMAP:NONE

INCLUDE    include\windows.inc
INCLUDE    include\user32.inc
INCLUDE    include\kernel32.inc 

.CODE

    jeden dd 1.0

DllEntry PROC hInstDLL:HINSTANCE, reason:DWORD, reserved1:DWORD

    mov eax, TRUE  
    ret

DllEntry ENDP

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------


srednia_harm     PROC

    push ebp
    mov esp,ebp

    push esi
    mov esi, [ebp+8] ; address of array
    mov ecx, [ebp+12] ; the number of elements

    finit
    fldz ; the current value of the sum - st(0)=0

    mianownik:
    fld dword PTR jeden ;ST(0)=1, ST(1)=sum

    fld    dword PTR [esi] ;loading of array elements - ST(0)=tab[i], ST(1)=1 ST(2)=suma

    fdivp st(1), st(0) ; st(1)=st(1)/(st0) -> ST(0)=1/tab[i], ST(1)=suma

    faddp st(1),st(0) ; st(1)=st(0)+st(1) -> st(0)=suma+1/tab[i]

    add esi,4
    loop mianownik

    pop esi
    pop ebp
    ret


srednia_harm  ENDP


;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
END DllEntry
```

**DEF:**

```
LIBRARY "biblioteka"
EXPORTS
srednia_harm
```

**C#:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace GUI
{
    unsafe class FunkcjeAsemblera //imports of assembler's function
    {
        [DllImport("bibliotekaASM.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern float srednia_harm(float[] table, int n);

        public float wywolajTest(float[] table, int n)
        {
            float wynik = srednia_harm(table, n);
            return wynik;
        }

    }
}
```

**C#:**

```
 private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FunkcjeAsemblera funkcje = new FunkcjeAsemblera();
            int n = 4;
            float[] table = new float[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                table[i] = 1;
            float wynik = funkcje.wywolajTest(table, n);
            textBox6.Text = wynik.ToString();
        }
```

When i run this code everything is fine. The result is 4 as I expected. But I tried to understand that code, so I set a lot of breakpoints in ASM function. Then the problems started. Arrat was exactly where it should be in memory but the seond parameter is lost. Address pointed to an empty field in the memory. I tried a lots of combinations, I changed types ant it still was the same.
I made some researched but i didn't find any clues. How it possible that when I run program everything works fine and in DEBUG not?

Comment: Debug and Release have different compiler output. The Debug version is compiled with optimizations off, while Release has optimizations on. They will yield different MSIL which will yield different machine code.

Comment: "but the seond parameter is lost." are you saying the under-laying variables have different values? Debug builds tend to force all variables to be zero, while in release it might optimize that away if its redundant.

Comment: You marked it StdCall but that is not what your wrote.  Use a C compiler to get this correct.  Or at least look at the assembly it generates so you'll understand what StdCall means.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I tested this in Debug and Release mode. I enabled Properties->Debug->EnableNativeCodedebugging. It works in both cases with Step Into(F11). The 'n'-variable is accessed properly.

One problem I noticed is an improper PROC setup. The code as above accesses the two variables relative to EBP but does not clean up the stack(stdcall [in which the callee is responsible for cleaning up the stack]@Wikipedia).

```
push        ebp  
mov         esp,ebp  
push        esi  
mov         esi,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp+0Ch]  
wait  
...
add         esi,4  
loop        6CC7101F  
pop         esi  
pop         ebp  
ret         <-- two params not cleaned up
```

The following is the code assembled by the PROC heading below:

```
push        ebp  
mov         ebp,esp  
push        esi  
mov         esi,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp+0Ch]  
wait  
... 
add         esi,4  
loop        6CC7101F  
pop         esi  
leave       <-- restores EBP
ret         8     <-- two params cleaned up
```

I suggest changing the PROC to

```
srednia_harm PROC uses esi lpArr: DWORD, num: DWORD
  mov esi, lpArr
  mov ecx, num
  ...
  ret
srednia_harm  ENDP
```

Maybe that has been the cause of some troubles.

Comment: Thx, now it's work ;) I have one more question. It is possible to move floating-point number from coprocessor to registers? I know that i have to use variable so I declare `var dd ?` and then i try `fst [var]` but it results: _An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in GUI.exe_

Comment: try putting the var 'jeden' in a '.data' segment. The code segment might be read  only.